# Dynamic Range date data annotation validation attribute c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, data-annotations

I want to implement a Data annotation attribute to validate dates.
I know something similar already exists like

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/2/2004", "3/4/2004", ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
```

But this code obliges me to set a static data. Instead I would like to set the name of a textbox that contains a data.

This will be the html code

```
<input type="text" name="startdate" />
<input type="text" name="enddate" />
```

and this the C# code

```
public class event {
   public ....
   [Range(DateTime.Today, "enddate")]
   public startdate {set;get;}
   [Range("startdate", "01/01/2014")]
   public enddate {set;get;}
}
```

Somebady can help me with the code? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah definitely. However not by standard data annotations.

Install `foolproof` nuget package and use its extra useful attributes! Examples of exactly what you need are [here](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/)